# Solr on Drupal HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, drupal, solr

I am having the following error when I try to visit my site Solr URL http://mysitename.com:8983/solr/admin/system

Please help, I spend many days try to solve this with no luck.

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /solr/admin/system. Reason:

```
ip-192-168-101-119: ip-192-168-101-119
```

java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-192-168-101-119: ip-192-168-101-119
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1461)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SystemInfoHandler.getCoreInfo(SystemInfoHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.SystemInfoHandler.handleRequestBody(SystemInfoHandler.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: I'm using AWS VPC with Drupal 7 with Solr Admin (drupal-4.1-solr-3.x)

Comment: I now solved the problem.

On my server host file (/etc/hosts) I just add the IP to be part of the localhost.

vi /etc/hosts

Add the following

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain ip-192-168-101-119

Hope it will help.